# Scrollable JTable: dispalying vertical scrollbar from the header level

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a scrollable JTable, with vertical scrollbar showed always. I need to move it, so it would start from where header does. How can I do this? Screenshot clears the situation.
[image]

Comment: You'd have to expand ScrollPaneLayout and provide your own layout logic. This you then use and apply to the scroll pane using the setLayout method

Comment: I woudn't be going vertical orienation for JTableHeader, put there shortcut, add ToolTip to the JTabelHeader, on mouse hoverover to put there some details, descriptions

Comment: I'm not a designer, that's not my work. I'll tell her about the corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- not possible, otherwise you'll scrolling with `JTableHeader` too
- [there are four corners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations)
- [you can to put there (J)Component](http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/creating-a-better-jtable/)